# How to hang curtains drywall with no gap

Tags: drywall, walls, hanging, drywall-anchor, curtain-rail

How can I hang curtains on an exterior wall that only has 1/2" between the interior(painted) drywall surface and the beginning of the exterior wall?

I tried to use a hollow wall anchor #6-32 x 1-1/4", but I wasn't able to hammer it into the correct depth. I don't want to go into the exterior wall.

I measured the depth of the hole and it only made it  1/2" into the wall. I know how to repair the wall if I need to start fresh.

Comment: If you really don't want to go into the exterior wall, perhaps you can glue (construction adhesive) a board to the wall and screw into that. If you ever have to remove the board, your drywall repair skills will come in handy.

Comment: Why don't you want to go into the wall? If it's drywall covering a concrete wall, your options are really limited without going into the concrete.

Comment: @Tester101 I have some apprehension about going into the wall. I don't know for sure what material it is. Any mistakes would be difficult to repair since it's behind the drywall